# /dev/tty.Serial* Missing in MacOS 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, serial-port, usb, tty, osx-mavericks

I'm not sure if this was as a result of a recent update to OSX 10.9, but for some reason, all the /dev/tty.Serial* and /dev/cu.Serial* targets are now missing, making serial communication with a connected USB device impossible, programatically.

I can see the USB device connecting in the "System Information" screens, and the device will connect appropriately with an installed instance of Windows running in a VMWare Fusion VM, but for the life of me, OSX will not give me a I/O-able target in /dev for the USB device. Did Apple move where the old /dev/tty.Serial* devices now hook into the system, or is this in fact just broken. I'm dead in the water until I can figure this out.

Comment: I have same problem too. I am using Adrduino and Firmata and the only way to make it working is to restart machine. Then it works until I disconnect device. So now I need to restart Mac every day I begin my work...

Comment: I thought it was just because my device wasn't connected, so I of course tried that, but with no luck. Nothing I do gets any of the /dev/tty.usbserial-* targets to re-appear. Very frustrating.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. There's a thread on Apple about it: https://discussions.apple.com/message/23717843#23717843

Comment: Same problem here. If I run `tail -f /var/log/system.log` I can see that the arduino leonardo is detected but it's not assigned a target in /dev. I just see the following message: `Nov 23 20:36:57 Dons-Mac-mini kernel[0]: AppleUSBCDCACMData: Version number - 4.2.1b2, Input buffers 8, Output buffers 16`

Comment: As with Mavericks and now El Capitan, I have the same issue using an FTDI Driver.  In El Capitan it shows up in /dev as tty.usbserial-xxxxxxxx.  It works for me until I remove the USB cable.  When I plug the cable back in, it does not make the driver in /dev.  I try another port, it works again.  After exhausting both ports, I will need to reboot.  I am looking for a way to reset this without rebooting my MBP.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get my FTDI Serial Cable to work by reinstalling the driver and rebooting the computer. This has not seemed to work for all cables, but at least it worked for one with an FTDI chip...

This TTL-232R-5V-AJ cable gave me the following messages in `/var/log/system.log`

```
Oct 29 18:22:27 doc com.apple.kextd[12]: kext com.FTDI.driver.FTDIUSBSerialDriver  202189000 is in exception list, allowing to load
Oct 29 18:22:27 doc kernel[0]: FTDIUSBSerialDriver:        0  4036001 start - ok
```

And:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root wheel 19, 12 Oct 29 18:22 /dev/tty.usbserial-FTWWVW3A
```

Comment: My problem is either over time, or as a result of system update, I've lost ALL targets in /dev that look like "/dev/tty.usbserial-*". What happened to them? I clearly still have serial ports, but now how are we supposed to interface to them or do any I/O with them? All thats left are the /dev/tty.Bluetooth-*, which is clearly not the target we're interested in...

Answer (score 0):

This install did the trick for me:
http://nozap.me/driver/osxpl2303/index.html

Since the driver is not signed, you will have to go to your System Preferences | Security & Privacy and Allow Apps from Anywhere (remember to change it back when done).

Now you will be able to install the software.  However, when you run it make sure to check the box to trust this DMG and not prompt you again... otherwise the actual driver will not be able to install.

No need to reboot your system after the install.  But you will have to disconnect and reconnect the USB, and restart your software and you should be all good to go.

Answer (score -2):

I had problems with the USB to serial cables under mac OS 10.9
I stumbled upon an answer that worked perfectly for me after trying many other things.  Many of the USB to serial are either prolific or clones of it.  I bought an Elecraft KX3 radio and while browsing their website found they gave a very detail pdf file about how to install under mac os. The info is contained within this [pdf](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_134_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_MAC_OSX.pdf)

Hope that helps some of you.